# Why disable interrupt before context switch

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, semaphore, interrupt

I was reading the OS textbook, in the synchronization chapter,it says :

> In particular,
>   most implementations of thread systems enforce the invariant that a thread
>   always disables interrupts before performing a context switch

Hence when writing `Aquire()` before go to sleep it will first disable interrupt.

My question is why interrupt disable is needed before context switch, is it use to protect the registers and keep the Aquire() atomic?

`Aquire()` is used before the critical section as:

```
Aquire(){
 disable interrupt;
 if (is busy){
    put on wait queue;
    sleep();
 }
 else set_busy;
 enable interrupt;
}
```

Go to sleep will implement context switch,why should we disable interrupt during context switch?Can we change the code to :

```
Aquire(){
 disable interrupt;
 if (is busy){
    enable interrupt;
    put on wait queue;
    sleep();
 }
 else set_busy;
 enable interrupt;
}
```

That is enables interrupt in thread A instead of letting other thread B after context switch(after A go to sleep) enable interrupt?

Comment: What is `Aquire()`?

Comment: There are many types of `aquire()`  ,I have corrected my question.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, a synchronization primitive requires updating multiple data locations *simultaneously*.  For example, a semaphore Acquire might require changing the state of the current thread to blocked, updating the count of the semaphore, removing the current thread from a queue and placing it on another queue.  Since simultaneously isn't really possible(*), it is necessary to devise an access protocol to simulate this.   In a single cpu system, the easiest way to do this is disable interrupts, perform the updates, then re-enable interrupts.  All software following this protocol will see the updates at once.

Multi-cpu systems typically need something extra to synchronize threads on separate cpus from interfering.  Disabling interrupts is insufficient, since that only affects the current cpu.  The *something extra* is typically a spin lock, which behaves much like a mutex or binary semaphore, except that the caller sits in a retry loop until it becomes available.

Even in the multi-cpu system, the operation has to be performed with interrupts disabled. Imagine Thread#0 has acquired a spinlock on cpu#0; then an interrupt on cpu#0 causes Thread#1 to preempt, and Thread#1 then attempts to acquire the same spinlock.  There are many scenarios which amount to this.

(*)  Transaction-al Memory provides something *like* this, but with limited applicability, and the implementation has to provide an independent implementation to ensure forward progress.  Also, since transactions do not nest, they really need to disable interrupts as well.

Comment: Note that while older compilers would regard all asm directives as potential memory clobbers, newer compilers ignore the possibility that operations like enabling and disabling interrupts might be used to guard accesses to objects that are used by other execution contexts, and "optimizations" that move accesses across interrupt enable/disable primitives are needlessly dangerous.

Comment: Reason number 532 to never use inline assembly; and so-called smart linkers are completely inappropriate for system code.

Comment: There's no reason that smart linkers shouldn't be able to support modes that are suitable for system code.  Very few programs would care about whether function calls are actually processed using function calls.  What is important is generally that a few key operations within functions not be reordered across operations in the calling code.  If tool designers would recognize that their customers know their *particular* needs better than the authors of standards ever could, it should be simple for them to add logic that would say that e.g. if a function performs any `volatile` accesses...

Comment: ...then "potential memory clobbers" need to be recognized as occurring somewhere between those accesses and the calling code.  Compiler writers insist that the notion that there has never been a tradition of treating `volatile` accesses as memory clobbers, but that's because calls to functions containing such accesses *were* (like calls to all other functions) treated as memory clobbers.  Someone writing a function that would rely upon `volatile` behaving as a memory clobber may be able to ensure that all accesses that would need to be guarded are `volatile`, but...

Comment: ...would often have no way to do so for calling code.